# How to find the job id of an action in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to cancel a job in spark, because sometimes it take more time and was not finished. a job is created when we call an action.
for example when i call collect and it takes more time to finish. i want to cancel the job of this action.
I don't use spark-submit, i create SparkContext in Scala code. and my application is a web based application based on GraphX.

How can i do this in spark?

Comment: please confirm if answer works for you if it works. Accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,

SparkContext.CancelGroupJob() can help to solve the problem. below link introduce the solution.
[CancelJobGroup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#cancelJobGroup-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```
val res = spark.sparkContext.applicationId
print(res)
//local-1593342096634res: String = local-1593342096634
```